# Use RegEx to mask certain fields in a JSON String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, regex

I am new to both NodeJS Javascript and Regular expressions. I have a JSON string, like so:

```
var jsonString = 
"[{\"ReturnCode\":0,\"TextID\":\"nwComputedSubTotal\",\"AccountNum\":\"958375845\",\"Status\":\"SomeStatus\"}]";
```

I have a small array of specific element names within this JSON string whose values I would like to mask with asterisks, like so:
`var fieldsToMask = ['TextID', 'AccountNum', 'ReturnCode'];`

Conditions: If an element name in this JSON string exists in the array fieldsToMask **AND** is 4 characters or longer, I want to display the first 2 characters of the value, and replace the other characters with asterisks. So for example, the AccountNumber element value should be `"AccountNum":"95*******"` and the TextID element value should be `"TextID":"nw****************"`. If the element name exists in array fieldsToMask **AND** is 3 characters or shorter, I just want to display 3 asterisks. So the ReturnCode element would be `"ReturnCode":"***"`. If the element name does **NOT** exist in the array, the value should display as is. So in this way, after masking, the entire xml string would look like:

```
[{"ReturnCode":"***","TextID":"nw****************","AccountNum":"95*******", "Status":"SomeStatus"}];
```

I have tried to write some code as you see below, but regular expressions are new to me and I find them pretty confusing. I am having trouble escaping the double quotes in the JSON string, and it is not working. **No JSON field is being masked at all.** Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var fieldsToMask = ['TextID', 'AccountNum', 'ReturnCode'];

fieldsToMask.forEach(function (field) {
  var regex = new RegExp("\"" + field + ":" + "\"" + "(.*?)", "g");
  jsonString = jsonString.replace(regex, function (match, p1) {
    if (p1.length > 3) {
        return field + ":" + p1.substring(0, 2) + "*".repeat(p1.length - 2);
      
    } 
    else {
      return field + ":" + "***";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You string is unlikely wrapped in double quotes unless all the double quotes in the string are escaped. Also why not JSON.parse it and just change the items in the array?

Comment: ``(.*?)`` at the end of the pattern matches nothing. Replace it with `(.*?)\"`

Comment: @mplungjan if I rewrote the string like this: `"[{\"ReturnCode\":0,\"TextID\":\"nwComputedSubTotal\",\"AccountNum\":\"958375845\",\"Status\":\"SomeStatus\"}]";` then how would I go about doing it?

Comment: @Rocker2982 Please visit this [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use regex and it is not recommended to manipulate the string.

Instead use a [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#the_reviver_parameter) function when parsing and then stringify it again if you need the JSON

```js
const fieldsToMask = ['TextID', 'AccountNum', 'ReturnCode', "NumReturnCode"];

const jsonString = `[{"ReturnCode":"05","NumReturnCode":5000,"TextID":"nwComputedSubTotal","AccountNum":"958375845", "Status":"SomeStatus"}]`;

const maskedFieldsReviver = (key, value) => {
  if (fieldsToMask.includes(key)) {
    const val = String(value);
    if (val) {
      const len = val.length;
      return (len <= 3) ? '***' : val.slice(0, 2).padEnd(len, '*');
    }
  }
  return value;
};

const arr = JSON.parse(jsonString, maskedFieldsReviver);
console.log(arr)
const jsonStringResult = JSON.stringify(arr);

console.log(jsonStringResult);
```

Alternatively parse the JSON and re[stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it with my function as a replacer function

```js
const fieldsToMask = ['TextID', 'AccountNum', 'ReturnCode', 'NumReturnCode'];

const jsonString = `[{"ReturnCode":"05","NumReturnCode":5000,"TextID":"nwComputedSubTotal","AccountNum":"958375845", "Status":"SomeStatus"}]`;

const maskFields = (key, value) => {
  if (fieldsToMask.includes(key)) {
    const val = String(value);
    if (val) {
      const len = val.length;
      return (len <= 3) ? '***' : val.slice(0, 2).padEnd(len, '*');
    }
  }
  return value;
};

const arr = JSON.parse(jsonString);
const maskedJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr, maskFields, 2);

console.log(maskedJsonString);
```

Comment: This worked magnificently. You are a life saver.

Comment: I see what you mean @CasimiretHippolyte Fixed - although that will change a numeric field to string

Comment: @Rocker2982 Please see updated code. I chopped off two chars at the end by mistake

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ah, I forgot about that, I added it.

Comment: Also added a replacer version